# Ruby/ RVM installation issues, possibly need to reformat /bin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, installation, rvm

I am trying to install rvm

I have the following commands

```
rvm get stable

rvm requirements
```

The error after rvm requirements is

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin' is not at first place,
```

from a quick internet search, I did the following

```
echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

Now I think the issue is that I have multiple ruby installed in the the bin folder, however I don't know how to fix it, a quick internet search leads me to this

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4417119

which suggest I edit my .bash_profile

my current .bash_profile looks like this

```
##
# Your previous /Users/secret/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/secret/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-08-19_at_17:35:01
##

#MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-08-19_at_17:35:01: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/secret/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/secret/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-08-19_at_17:42:44
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-08-19_at_17:42:44: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

However I am completely unfamiliar with editing .bash_profile, and hesitate to do the same thing, can anyone explain what does the following do, and how will it solve my situation?

```
export
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbina
```

Thanks

Edit:

I have tried

```
export
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbina
```

as Stephan recommended, although the problem persist

Edit 2:

I have also tried

```
rvm --debug get head
```

which returned

Upgrade Notes:

```
  * WARNING: you have 'rvm_configure_env' in /etc/rvmrc, run the following to fix:

      sudo sed -i'' -e "/rvm_configure_env=.*\/opt\/sm/d" /etc/rvmrc
      rvm autolibs smf
```

I tried both command, I still get

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin' is not at first place,
```

when

```
rvm requirements
```

Edit:

Tried

```
rvm install ruby-head
```

Comment: Backup .bash_profile and hack away :p.

Comment: `export PATH=...` makes the environment variable `PATH` available to all commands in the life span of the `bash` shell it is invoked from